# @OneToOne With @JoinColumn that holds only the UUID instead of the whole object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I'm using Java + Spring + Hibernate

When testing the following code, I'm getting an error:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by
>   reflection getter of com.XXX.XXX.entity.Policy.id

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "assignment")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Assignment extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    @NotTracked
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Policy.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "policy_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "policy_id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @TrackedEntity(isIdentityField = true)
    private UUID policyID;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "policy")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region = "policy")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Policy extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "policy_id")
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    @NotTracked
    private UUID id;

    ...
    ...
    ..

}
```

When changing the `private UUID policyID;` from `UUID` to `Policy`, its working just fine, is there a way to set somehow a reference to specific object inside Policy as ID instead of holding the whole object of policy inside the Assignment object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to include just the UUID, but it will not be a hibernate managed FK any longer. I don't advise this as you want Hibernate to manage your FK.. You would simply change `Assignment` to:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "assignment")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Assignment extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    @NotTracked
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name="policy_id")
    private UUID policyID;
}
```

With that being said, you will lose all Cascade options and FK check constraints against this field unless you add them to your database manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no reason for using the UUID instead of the reference to the Policy-Object.
You can annotate that you want to lazy load the object, so it is only loaded from the database if you want to access another attribute of the Policy-Object:

@OneToOne(targetEntity = Policy.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)